# Remove indices of multiple lists if they are equal

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, indexing

I am trying to remove indices from two lists, if in both lists the given index value equals 0. Below I have coded a way to do this, but my real life data set includes >11K lists and >30K indices per list.

So my question is there an easier/ more efficient way of doing this?

```
data = [[8,0,3,0,1,0,1],[1,0,2,8,0,0,3]]

# taking the sum of indices across all arrays if it equals 0 you know that that index is 0 across all arrays
sum_dict = {}
for array in data:
    for i in range(len(array)):
        value = array[i]
        if i not in sum_dict:
            sum_dict[i] = value
        else:
            sum_dict[i] += value

# removing indices that have sum=0 in all arrays and create "clean" data
clean_data = []
sum_dict = {key:val for key, val in sum_dict.items() if val == 0}
for array in data:
    for i in sorted(list(sum_dict.keys()), reverse=True):
        del array[i]
    clean_data.append(array)        

print(clean_data)
```

output:

```
[[8, 3, 0, 1, 1], [1, 2, 8, 0, 3]]
```

Comment: This is a great example of why it's important to post clear code. Your prose is a bit hard to follow on its own, as is the code. But together, you have a very nice clear question that I'll be happy to answer. Good job OP!

Comment: Are all the lists the same length? Or is data ragged?

Comment: Thanks, I'll be happy to take your suggestions! If something is not clear, please let me know!

Comment: @pr94, if the two sublists are not of the same length, e.g. `data = [[1,2,0],[3,4]]`, what should be the output

Comment: All lists are indeed of equal length, the position in the list indicates a given feature. E.g. index 5 in both lists displays the value of feature x. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this that I can think of is to use numpy. This is especially true if all the lists in `data` are the same length:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array(data)
sums = data.sum(axis=0)
clean_data = data[:, sums.astype(bool)]
```

Probably a slightly faster, but much less memory efficient way to compute the mask would be

```
mask = (data != 0).any(axis=0)
clean_data = data[:, mask]
```

If your data is ragged, or you just want to use plain python for some other reason, there's a better way for that as well. You can start with a list of zeros the size of your longest datum. A dictionary is not necessary since a list is a better mapping of int to value for contiguous indices.

```
maxlen = max(len(d) for d in data)
sums = [0] * maxlen
```

Updating the sums is fairly straightforward. One option is to use `zip`:

```
for d in data:
    sums[:len(d)] = [s + t for s, t in zip(sums, d)]
```

Cleaning up the data can be facilitated by [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
clean_data = [list(compress(d, sums)) for d in data]
```

This is only if you're a masochist and the data is ragged. If the data is not ragged and you can't use numpy, use the transposition idiom in [@DeveshKumarSingh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59512729/2988730).

Comment: Wow, that's a a much optimized version using numpy

Comment: @Devesh. Yeah, these arrays are a few MB, so I'd guess a couple of orders of magnitude speedup at least.

Comment: Ran it on the real life dataset of >11K sublists with >30K indices. Runs in less than 10 seconds (your first option). Great!

Comment: @pr94. >300MB is big, but numpy is fast :) I'd bet that a significant portion of that time was spent just converting the data. If you could load straight into an array buffer, it would help a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over both lists together, and consider the elements only when both of them are not equal to 0. You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate on both elements together

```
data = [[8,0,3,0,1,0,1],[1,0,2,8,0,0,3]]

result = []
for i, j in zip(*data):

    # Only consider the elements if both i and j are not equal to 0
    if not (i == j and i == 0):
        result.append((i, j))

result = [list(data) for data in zip(*result)]
print(result)
```

The output is

```
[[8, 3, 0, 1, 1], [1, 2, 8, 0, 3]]
```

For a more general case of multiple sublists, you can use as follows

```
result = []
for elements in zip(*data):

    # Only consider if it is not the case that all elements are equal to 0
    if not all(x==0 for x in elements):
        result.append(elements)

result = [list(data) for data in zip(*result)]
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks your second piece of code indeed seems to work. I am running it on the real dataset as we speak.

Comment: The set conversion seems inefficient. If you're going to check whether each element is zero, you don't need to use a hash table to facilitate: `all(x==0 for x in elements)` will do, and is probably much faster

Comment: Both `all` and the set conversion is `O(n)` time, but I guess `all` is space efficient and can short circuit faster?

Comment: Yes, and `all` doesn't build a hash table. Not all `O(n)` algorithms are equally fast

Comment: Yes, best case time complexity is better for `all`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([[8,0,3,0,1,0,1],[1,0,2,8,0,0,3]])
data = data.loc[:, data.sum(axis=0) != 0]
print(data.values)

"""
[[8 3 0 1 1]
 [1 2 8 0 3]]
"""
```

Comment: Yes thought of this way as well. Yet, loading the real life dataset into a pandas dataframe is really inefficient. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution :

```
data = [[8,0,3,0,1,0,1],[1,0,2,8,0,0,3]]

intermediate = ( x for x in zip(*data) if not (x == (0, 0) ) )

result = [ list(item) for item in zip(*intermediate) ]

print(result)
```